# Dynamically Adding React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

**Background**: I have created a working application with React, Redux using ES6. Webpack is used as a bundler with CommonJS pattern.

**Required**:  I have created another file that has react component in it. Now I want to switch component based on some global parameter value. I have added an if condition inside the render method. Refer code below -

```
const LPage = () => {   
    let resource = window.keys;

    if(window.switchComponent == 0)
    {
        return (
            <div className="container containerHome">       
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <a className="logo spriteMobile"></a>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return window.AnotherComponent(); 
    }    
};
```

This works fine for stateless component. I had to write something like this to use external component.

```
window.React = React;
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
```

Now I am not able to replace Stateful Components in this way. They have to fire actions and update store. Is there any way to replace/switch these stateful components using some external javascript?

Answer (score 0):

First off, `window.AnotherComponent()` is not how you're supposed to instantiate components in React. The correct way here would be `return <window.AnotherComponent />`. If you need to pass properties, you can do it as well: `return <window.AnotherComponent foo={true}/>`

Now, doing it the way you do it is very un-React-like. For once, in case the value of `window.switchComponent` changes, your component will not be re-rendered, because React would have no way of knowing that the component's state has changed. There are other ways to provide global configuration values down the component trees, like for example setting them in the Redux store (which you already have set up anyway).

Comment: It is not necessary to always return <window.AnotherComponent/>. This code gets converted to normal js which just returns a React Component. Now if I have a function window.AnotherComponent() that returns a component that would make a perfect sense. For the other part, I am looking for a way to access to Redux store and other config and settings.